# changing a sql view query into a relational algebra?

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle, view, relational-algebra

I want to convert this sql query into relational algebra.

sql query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Library
WHERE libName='florence'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you mean with *convert to* relational algebra. But in relational algebra that sentence would be:

[image]

Basically, the `SELECT` operation over the `Library` table, with a condition.

Answer (score -1):

that view is the same as the result of:

```
SELECT *
FROM Library
WHERE libName='florence'
```

Comment: yeh basically, but i want to know how to convert it into relational alegbra

Comment: to me sql is relational algebra although not really the best one